# How to GPG sign a file that is built by Travis-CI

Tags: travis-ci, gpg-signature

I see that Travis has a workflow for encrypting a files, [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files/).

My use case is slightly simpler, I just want to generate a signature for a file that has been built on Travis-CI.
Say:

```
hello-0.0.1-a.bin.asc
hello-0.0.1-a.bin
pubkey.gpg 
<or> hello-0.0.1-a.pub
```

In this case `hello-0.0.1-a.bin` is created by a Travis build, and will be pushed to Github as a release.
Likewise the signature must also be pushed to Github as a release (i.e. under the same tag).

I don't strongly care (i.e. not a deal breaker) if the private/public key-pair is unique to that build.
But it would be ideal if the private/public key-pair is shared between builds.

Appreciate and hints tips or incantations.

Comment: Normally in public signature system the key pair is reusable (if you keep the private key safe of course). The main problem is really forwarding you public key to recipients in a trustable way, otherwise hackers could have their own public key used by your recipients, and their signature would look OK and yours would look forged. Using one-shot keys as some recommend requires that you have to establish a safe canal for updates of the public key, which is what you are already trying to do for the executable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It basically comes down to a few steps.

1. Export the secret keys from your gpg keyring `gpg --export-secret-keys > all.gpg`
2. Use the `travis` ruby gem to `encrypt-file` the gpg keyring (ex `all.gpg`)
3. Add `all.gpg.enc` to your repo (NOT the unencrypted `all.gpg`)
4. Make sure that the repo can access secure variables
5. Add this line to your `.travis.yml` file to decrypt your encrypted private signing key

   `openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_0a6446eb3ae3_key -iv $encrypted_0a6446eb3ae3_key -in all.gpg.enc -out all.gpg -d`
6. Import the gpg keys `gpg --import all.gpg`
7. Sign your image `gpg --output hello.bin.asc --sign hello.bin`

> ```
> $ travis encrypt-file all.gpg --add
> encrypting all.gpg for rkh/travis-encrypt-file-example
> storing result as all.gpg.enc
> storing secure env variables for decryption
>
> Make sure to add all.gpg.enc to the git repository.
> Make sure not to add all.gpg to the git repository.
> Commit all changes to your .travis.yml.
> ```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment on an old-ish answer, but how secure is this? I understand that Travis's `password: secure:` approach for passwords is secure. But this results in an unencrypted private key getting dumped into the Travis build directory. Is there for sure no way for the private key file details to be retrieved from someone browsing the build results on travis-ci.org?

Comment: @NickWilliams that's all dependent on how the build is run in travis. since the `secure` environment variables are unavailable to pull requests, there's no way a third party could modify the project to expose the secret. if the secure environment variable is ever output to the terminal or saved to an artifact for deployment in the original project (or by a project maintainer), it could be exposed. in my opinion, this risk is equal to a accidental exposure by other vectors

Comment: It seems like the common thread is that you have to trust the server. As @StephenG says, there is a non-zero risk. You probably need to determine trust in a server on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: What is $encrypted_0a6446eb3ae3_key?  Where do we get the value of this (travis) variable?